# Órfão pode ser adjectivo sem género?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, adjetivos

No dicionário priberam a palavra órfão, figura como nome e adjectivo masculino mas também como adjectivo sem género:

> [Órfão](https://dicionario.priberam.org/orf%C3%A3o)
>
> órfão | adj. n. m. | adj.

O feminino, Órfã, tem a entrada só como nome feminino

> [Orfã](https://dicionario.priberam.org/orf%C3%A3)
>
> órfã | n. f.
> fem. sing. de órfão

A minha pergunta é se podem dar um ou dois exemplos de frases em que órfão seja usado como adjectivo sem género, por comparação com outra frase em que seja adjectivo masculino.

Comment: Quando pesquiso no [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/%C3%B3rf%C3%A3), vejo duas entradas: *órfão* e *órfã*. Do primeiro, o Priberam diz ser flexão do feminino do singular de *órfão*, e do segundo diz ser o substantivo feminino *órfã*. Mas não entendi sua pergunta: como o adjetivo pode ser sem gênero? O adjetivo pode ser de dois gêneros, como *matável*, mas não sei de adjetivo sem gênero. Está pedindo um exemplo onde o gênero gramatical *órfão* não faça inferência de gênero biológico? como em «ela é órfão»?.

Comment: @Schilive sinceramente não sei, estou confundido (é talvez de ler gramáticas a mais)... Então se o adjectivo for dito "uniforme" ou de 2 géneros, tipo "o homem feliz, a mulher feliz" como se aplica um exemplo desses trivial ao orfão? Repara o verbete para [azul](https://dicionario.priberam.org/azul) diz "2 géneros" na etiqueta, não é so Adj sem indicação nenhuma de género como no verbete órfão. Mas se conseguires escreve um contributo como resposta (nem que seja só parcial) e se a pergunta tiver algum erro eu edito.

Comment: Também não ajuda as gramáticas e os dicionários misturarem termos como uniforme, invariável e de "2 géneros". Outra nota, acho que só para os substantivos é obrigatório as palavras terem género, os adjectivos podem não ter género (algo assim)?!

Comment: Quando eu abro o site do Priberam, eu não vejo "adjectivo sem género" para órfão, vejo "adjectivo". E vejo o mesmo para "branco" e "seco".

Comment: Parece que "adj. n. m." refere a frase "adjectivo e **n**ome masculino".

Comment: @DanGetz boa explicação, tentei ver as secções "como usar dicionário" e algumas das abreviaturas não são explicadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Também creio que é um erro de leitura das abreviaturas do dicionário — que podiam ser mais claras...

A [definição no Priberam da palavra órfão](https://dicionario.priberam.org/%C3%B3rf%C3%A3o) indica que ela pode ser *um adjectivo ou nome masculino*, nas suas duas primeiras aceções, ou *um adjetivo* na sua terceira aceção.

Com clarificações minhas a negrito e dentro de parêntesis rectos:

> órfão | **[1 e 2:]** adj. n. m. | **[3]** adj.
>
> ór·fão
> (latim *orphanus*, -i)
>
> adjectivo e nome masculino
>
> 1. Diz-se da ou pessoa menor privada de pai, de mãe ou de ambos os pais.
> 2. [Figurado]  Que ou quem perdeu alguém que estimava ou que o protegia.
>
> adjectivo
>
> 3. Privado, abandonado, desamparado.

"órfão", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/%C3%B3rf%C3%A3o [consultado em 08-08-2022].

Comment: Depois cheguei a esta conclusão, mas antes tive de ler bastantes recursos para ter a certeza que só há 4 combinações possiveis para género em português: masculino, feminino, 2 géneros, e sem género.

Comment: Certo? É tão fácil às vezes perdermo-nos nos pormenores e imprecisões da escrita, quando falado seria tão simples de perceber!... A definição feminina, órfã, também não diz que pode ser um adjetivo, e isso confundiu-me ao tentar encontrar a resposta ótima... até que percebi que era apenas "feminino de X, ver X" e que não tinha significado o facto de não ser indicado como adjetivo feminino.

Comment: Como eu o entedi, o "orfão" adjectivo significa "último", "único" ou "isolado". Por exemplo: *"O nó orfão no grafo"* ou *"o último feijão no frasco é orfão"*, mas depois procurando um substantivo feminino não dispensa a concordância de género "foi a única borla, era borla orfã" (borla ou aventura orfão - não soa bem). Portanto, o dicionário no verbete "orfã" devia dizer Adjectivo feminino... O essencial para mim foi tirar dúvidas sobre a possibilidade de um "género neutro" ou que a possibilidade de "sem género" é muito restrita a palavras como pronomes e artigos, e.g  "isto" ou "aquilo".